# How to iterate over the first dimension of each operand using nditer?

Tags: python, numpy, iterator

Given:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6)
b = np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)
```

I want something like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    v1 = a[i]
    v2 = b[i,...]
```

but I can't figure out how to do it using nditer?

```
it = np.nditer((a,b))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7fe57c985cae> in <module>()
----> 1 it = np.nditer((a,b))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6) (6,4)
```

This works for a single operand, but how do I do it for operands of different rank?

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
for x in np.nditer(a, flags=['external_loop'], order='F'):
...     print x,
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `zip`?

```
>>> for i in xrange(len(a)):
...     print a[i],b[i,...]
... 
0 [0 1 2 3]
1 [4 5 6 7]
2 [ 8  9 10 11]
3 [12 13 14 15]
4 [16 17 18 19]
5 [20 21 22 23]
>>> for v1,v2 in zip(a,b):
...     print v1,v2
... 
0 [0 1 2 3]
1 [4 5 6 7]
2 [ 8  9 10 11]
3 [12 13 14 15]
4 [16 17 18 19]
5 [20 21 22 23]
```